# createFragment() method at FragmentStateAdapter() doesn't run again after creating new instance of adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I use ViewPager2 and Navigation Component. In my application settings I have an option to control number of fragments("appMode" option below) in ViewPager2 and which fragment must be first("primaryScreen" option below). In my adapter I check that option and create necessary fragments:

```
override fun getItemCount() = if (appMode == "both") 2 else 1

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when (primaryScreen) {
        "notes" -> if (position == 0) NotesFragment() else TasksFragment()
        else -> if (position == 0) TasksFragment() else NotesFragment()
    }
}
```

But when I get back to my ViewPager, nothing changes, until I restart my app. I have no idea why it's not working, if I nullify ViewPager adapter in my onDestroyView():

```
b.viewPager.adapter = null
adapter = null
```

This is how I apply adapter to my ViewPager2:

```
private var adapter: VPAdapter? = null

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    adapter = VPAdapter(this)
    b.viewPager.adapter = adapter
}
```

Full code of my ViewPager2 adapter:

```
class VPAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    private val prefs by lazy {
        fragment.requireContext().getSharedPreferences("MainSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) }

    private var appMode
        get() = prefs.getString("appMode", "both")
        set(value) = prefs.edit { putString("appMode", value) }

    private var primaryScreen
        get() = prefs.getString("primaryScreen", "notes")
        set(value) = prefs.edit { putString("primaryScreen", value) }

    override fun getItemCount() = if (appMode == "both") 2 else 1

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        println("createFragment") // I use it to detect when it runs
        return when (primaryScreen) {
            "notes" -> if (position == 0) NotesFragment() else TasksFragment()
            else -> if (position == 0) TasksFragment() else NotesFragment()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: @user4097210 should I do that, even if I nullify both adapter variable and viewpager adapter itself?